# Apply a cross validated ML model to unseen data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I would like to use scikit learn to predict with X a variable y. I would like to train a classifier on a training dataset using cross validation and then to apply this classifier to an unseen test dataset (as in https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04492-9)

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Import dataset
X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# Create binary variable y
y[y == 0] = 1

# Divide in train and test set 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=75, random_state=4, stratify=y)

# Cross validation on the train data  
cv_model = cross_validate(model, x_train, y_train, cv=5)
```

Now I would like to use this cross validated model and to apply it to the unseen test set. I am unable to find how.

It would be something like

```
result = cv_model.score(x_test, y_test)
```

Except this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that; you need to *fit* the model before using it to predict new data. `cross_validate` is just a convenience function to get the scores; as clearly mentioned in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html), it returns just that, i.e. *scores*, and not a (fitted) model:

> Evaluate metric(s) by cross-validation and also record fit/score times.
>
> [...]
>
> Returns:   **scores : *dict of float arrays of shape (n_splits,)***
>
> Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation.
>
> A dict of arrays containing the score/time arrays for each scorer is returned.